# where is android 2.1?

Tags: android

In my android sdk installation, I have a lot of platforms, anyway there is an android 2.1-update1 but I cant find, even in the available packages of Sdk Manager an android 2.1 platform, I mean just android 2.1 without update1.

does anybody knows where is android 2.1?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.1 has been superseded by Android2.1-update1, which is why it is no longer offered.

Comment: I believe that the Nexus One is the only phone that ever had Android 2.1.  Every other 2.1 phone is running 2.1-update1.